# what does this ruby code mean?

Tags: double, variable-assignment

this code fails:

```
@user_pages, @users = paginate :users, :per_page => 40, :order => :name
```

rewriting it like this works:

```
@users = User.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 40)
```

but what does `@user_pages`, `@users` mean?

I take it that `@users` is being assigned to `@user_pages`?

joey

Comment: Which version of rails you are using? And which pagination gem?

Answer (score 0):

No, `@user_pages` and `@users` are two different values returned from an array of values.  They are, in effect, `value[0]` and `value[1]`.

An irb example should help:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ me$ irb
1.9.3-p429 :001 > a,b = [1,2]
 => [1, 2]
1.9.3-p429 :002 > a
 => 1
1.9.3-p429 :003 > b
 => 2
```